# What's the best C# code highlighting plugin for wordpress?

Tags: c#, wordpress, plugins, codehighlighter

Best would be if it performs the highlighting exactly as it is in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're using Visual Studio, you can try the [Copy Source as HTML plugin](http://www.jtleigh.com/people/colin/software/CopySourceAsHtml/).

An non-Visual Studio alternative would be [SyntaxHighlighter](http://code.google.com/p/syntaxhighlighter/) (more info [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BestCodeSyntaxHighlighterForSnippetsInYourBlog.aspx))

Comment: wow, thats a nice alternative!! i will wait a bit if there will be a good suggestion for a proper WP plugin .. otherwise I will accept this as the best answer.

Comment: First link is dead.

Answer (score 1):

Probably [SyntaxHighlighter Evolved](http://www.viper007bond.com/wordpress-plugins/syntaxhighlighter/), which uses a nice JavaScript ([SyntaxHighlighter 2.0](http://code.google.com/p/syntaxhighlighter/)) library for highlighting, and you can easily add custom styles.

Comment: i like that plugin but the only thing which makes it a no-go is: "NOTE: One important thing to watch out for is opening triangular bracket <. It must be replaced with an HTML equivalent of &lt; in all cases. Failure to do won't break the page, but might break the source code displayed. " Code normally contains a lot of brackets (<) and i have no time to encode them manually :(

Comment: In this case, you can use the editor for SyntaxHighlighter: http://precode.codeplex.com/